# Remove just 0 values from Chart Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have been trying to remove these 0 from the Excel Chart i have watched multiple videos used `Format Control #,##0;-#,##0;;.` and different things available on Google but nothing is happening. I have replace the 0 value with `Nothing#`.

Go to advance uncheck the `Show a zero in cells that have zero values`
then go to Select Data Source => Hidden and Empty Cells but still nothing happens.

Still issue is not resolved can someone please help me with this problem i will really appreciate the help.

If it can be resolve through VBA then please share the code or Manual Solution.

[image]

I have tried to write record the code but i really do not know how to do this.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Points(9).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(9).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(9).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(8).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(6).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(5).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub
```

I have tried with this one but it removes all the labels rather than 0.

```
Sub chartth()

Sheet5.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False Then
            .Points(i).Select
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
                If .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
                    .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
                    .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
                End If
        ElseIf .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
            .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
            .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
        End If
    Next i
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False Then
            .Points(i).Select
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
                If .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
                    .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
                    .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
                End If
        ElseIf .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
            .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
            .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
        End If
    Next i
End With


With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False Then
            .Points(i).Select
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
                If .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
                    .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
                    .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
                End If
        ElseIf .Points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
            .Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
            .Points(i).DataLabel.ShowValue = False
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: This is connected to multiple years so when i changed the year data is loaded accordingly. If i remove the 0 then which data have values greater than 0 will not show as well

Comment: First attempt means ? @BigBen

Comment: The second snippet looks pretty close to what the answer should be... may be able to take a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like the following, which applies data labels to each `Series`, then loops over the `Point`s in each `Series` and removes the `DataLabel` if it's 0.

```
Sub ApplyLabelsAndClearZeros(ByVal chrt As Chart)
    Dim ser As Series
    For Each ser In chrt.SeriesCollection
        ser.ApplyDataLabels
        
        Dim pnt As Point
        For Each pnt In ser.Points       
            If pnt.DataLabel.Text = "0" Then
                pnt.HasDataLabel = False
            End If          
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like the following:

```
Sub Test()
    ApplyLabelsAndClearZeros Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart
End Sub
```